# Automate data validation between Redshift and Tableau Server

Tags: amazon-redshift, tableau-api

**Hi, I'd like to ask you about automating utilization table-data verification between Redshift and Tableau Server.**

**- Environment** : Redshift(8.0.0)(DBeaver 23.0.4) is connected to Tableau Server(2021.1.4 64bit Windows), and Redshift's tables are periodically compressed and loaded on the tableau server.

**- Problem** : Redshift's various table-column often needs to be deleted and modified.
However, these tables are loaded in the form of compressed files on the Tableau Server, and may actually be used in dashboards.
Therefore, in order to modify and delete the table, I had no choice but to enter the table server and check it one by one.

It is our desire to automate this process.

---

**To sum up**

0. Tables in Redshift are periodically compressed and loaded on the Tableau Server

1. Need to modify/delete tables that exist on Redshift from time to time

2. But there is a possibility that the table is being used in the tableau server, so it is inconvenient to enter the tableau server and check it directly

3. Need something to help you check this process automatically

---

**For example,**

1. `t1` and `t2` tables exist in the Redshift `A` schema approaching DBeaver
2. Loads both `t1` and `t2` tables into Tableau Server as compressed files
3. Redshift administrator wants to modify column `c1` in table `t1`
4. At this time, you need a way to automatically check whether the `t1` table or `c1` column is being utilized on the tableau server-dashboard without visiting the tableau server directly!

---

I couldn't find a way..

Thank you!!

Comment: don't expose Redshift tables; use views with schemabinding instead....

Comment: When you say load the tables as compressed files, are you loading a csv/text file? If so, why not just connect to a redshift table and publish it as a data source?
Yes, you can check if a table/field is being used with the meta data api https://help.tableau.com/current/api/metadata_api/en-us/index.html